# Ebean/idIn Parameter not set

Tags: orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am having a weird problem with Ebean.

Code:

```
static <T> ImmutableMap<Long, T> getFromIdToItemMap(Iterable<SqlRow> rows, 
        Callable<Model.Finder<Long, T>> getFinder, 
        String idSqlFieldName, 
        Function<T, Long> getId) {
    List<Long> tfzIds = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (SqlRow i : rows) {
        tfzIds.add((long) i.getLong(idSqlFieldName));
    }
    Builder<Long, T> id_to_tfz = new ImmutableMap.Builder<Long, T>();
    List<T> tfzs;
    try {
        tfzs = getFinder.call().where().idIn(tfzIds).findList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    for (T tfz : tfzs) {
        id_to_tfz.put(getId.apply(tfz), tfz);
    }
    return id_to_tfz.build();
}
```

Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
select t0.virtuelle_adresse c0, t0.reale_adresse c1, t0.betr_nr c2, t0.bemerkung c3, t0.inbetriebnahme c4, t0.dekoder_typ_id c5, t0.model_tfz_typ_id c6, t0.eigentuemer_id c7 
from tfz t0 
where t0.virtuelle_adresse in (?)  [90012-168] 
Bind values:[] 
Query was:
select t0.virtuelle_adresse c0, t0.reale_adresse c1, t0.betr_nr c2, t0.bemerkung c3, t0.inbetriebnahme c4, t0.dekoder_typ_id c5, t0.model_tfz_typ_id c6, t0.eigentuemer_id c7 
from tfz t0 
where t0.virtuelle_adresse in (?)  


    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:815)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:795)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.findMany(CQueryEngine.java:210)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.DefaultOrmQueryEngine.findMany(DefaultOrmQueryEngine.java:77)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.findList(OrmQueryRequest.java:272)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findList(DefaultServer.java:1502)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.findList(DefaultOrmQuery.java:904)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.util.DefaultExpressionList.findList(DefaultExpressionList.java:177)
    at controllers.Prognosis.getFromIdToItemMap(Prognosis.java:106)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
select t0.virtuelle_adresse c0, t0.reale_adresse c1, t0.betr_nr c2, t0.bemerkung c3, t0.inbetriebnahme c4, t0.dekoder_typ_id c5, t0.model_tfz_typ_id c6, t0.eigentuemer_id c7 
from tfz t0 
where t0.virtuelle_adresse in (?)  [90012-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.expression.Parameter.checkSet(Parameter.java:73)
    at org.h2.command.Prepared.checkParameters(Prepared.java:163)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:85)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:191)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:109)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeQuery(PreparedStatementHandle.java:172)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQuery.prepareBindExecuteQuery(CQuery.java:382)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.query.CQueryEngine.findMany(CQueryEngine.java:174)
    ... 32 more
```

I don't understand how the tfzIds list did not get inserted into the query built by EBean.

What I tried: I added the cast to long to ensure that I don't get nulls in the list. But that doesn't seem the be the problem, the list is not read at all it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurred because `rows` was empty... I am surprised EBean did not check for that. I solved the issue by asserting that rows `hasNext()` as the first statement of the method, thereby provoking a more useful Exception.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @pktangyue: Why not? I asked the question, so surely, I must know?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Thanks a lot, this was driving me mad, was searching everywhere else. I'd call this an Ebean bug.